# Converting a list of strings to ints (or doubles) in Python

Tags: python, list, int, double

I have a lots of list of strings that look similar to this:

```
list = ['4', '-5', '5.763', '6.423', '-5', '-6.77', '10']
```

I want to convert it to a list of ints (or doubles) but the `-` keeps producing an error.

Comment: whats the code you have that produces the error?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
>>> lst = ['4', '-5', '5.763', '6.423', '-5', '-6.77', '10']
>>> map(float, lst)
[4.0, -5.0, 5.763, 6.423, -5.0, -6.77, 10.0]
```

And don't use `list` as a variable name

Comment: This seems to give a map but the question was to make a list...

Answer (score 8):

for Python 3:

```
listOfStrings = ['4', '-5', '5.763', '6.423', '-5', '-6.77', '10']
listOfFloats = list(map(float, listOfStrings))
```

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> [float(x) for x in ['4', '-5', '5.763', '6.423', '-5', '-6.77', '10']]
[4.0, -5.0, 5.763, 6.423, -5.0, -6.77, 10.0]
```