# how to change list ['1'],['2'],['3'] to 1,2,3 in python

Tags: python, list

I would like to change

```
mylist = [['1'],['2'],['3']]
```

to be

```
mynewlist = (1,2,3)
```

How to do that in python ?

Comment: I'm not sure if you are aware that `(1,2,3)` is a tuple and not a list. Which specifically do you want to end up with? The tuple `(1,2,3)`, or the list `[1,2,3]`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flattening a shallow list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python) and [Converting a list of strings to ints (or doubles) in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722882/converting-a-list-of-strings-to-ints-or-doubles-in-python) and many others.

Comment: hmm.. my goal is to put "mynewlist" into a odbc connection --> cursor.execute("select x from table where list in (?),(mynewlist))

Answer (score 7):

A simple list comprehension will do:

```
mynewlist = [int(x[0]) for x in mylist]
```

Of course, if you actually want a tuple as output:

```
mynewtuple = tuple(int(x[0]) for x in mylist)
```

Comment: Hi mgilson, I'm trying to get csv to use in a where statement using odbc within python something like " where id in (list) " .. if that explains ...